# Proving a relation between Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem:

> If $$(1+i)(1+2i)(1+3i)...(1+ni)=x+iy$$Prove that $$2\times 5\times 10...(1+n^2)=x^2+y^2$$

I would be \grateful if somebody would help me.

PS:  $ i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: What do you suppose would be $x-iy = \overline{(x+iy)}$?  Note that $x^2+y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy)$.  Note also that $\overline{u\cdot v} = \overline{u}\cdot \overline{v}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$(1+i)(1+2i)(1+3i)...(1+ni)=x+iy$$

Now Taking Modulus on both side, We get

$$\displaystyle \left|(1+i)(1+2i)(1+3i)...(1+ni)\right| = \left|x+iy\right|$$

So $$\displaystyle \left|(1+i)\right|\cdot \left|(1+2i)\right|\cdot \left|(1+3i)\right|...\left|(1+ni)\right|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

So $$\displaystyle 2\cdot 5\cdot 10 \cdot \left(1+n^2\right) = x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT....take the modulus of both sides and square both sides. Use the fact that $|z_1z_2|=|z_1|\times|z_2|$

Comment: I haven't used Polar forms. My hint is the same as the full solution by juantheron

Comment: You can prove it using algebra by writing $z_1=a+ib$, $z_2=c+id$ and using this identity https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta–Fibonacci_identity

Answer (score 1):

So, you have the following
$$
\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + ni) = x + iy
$$
then, $\overline{x + iy} = x - iy$, and
$$
\overline {\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + ni)} = \prod \limits_{i = 1}^n \overline{(1 + ni)} = \prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 - ni) = x - iy
$$
Now multiply one to another
$$
\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + ni) \prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 - ni) = (x + iy)(x - iy) \\
\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + ni)(1 - ni) = x^2 + y^2 \\
\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + n^2) = x^2 + y^2
$$